# Calling for executables not yet installed displays a message in German

Tags: system-language

Calling any executable which is not yet installed results in a message which is not easy to understand:

```
$ tcl
Der Befehl \xbbtcl\xab wurde nicht gefunden, meinten Sie vielleicht:
 Befehl \xbbtel\xab aus dem Paket \xbborville-write\xab (universe)
 Befehl \xbbtc\xab aus dem Paket \xbbiproute2\xab (main)
 Befehl \xbbtcs\xab aus dem Paket \xbbtcs\xab (universe)
 Befehl \xbbtjl\xab aus dem Paket \xbbpvm-examples\xab (universe)
 Befehl \xbbcl\xab aus dem Paket \xbbcl-launch\xab (universe)
 Befehl \xbbecl\xab aus dem Paket \xbbecl\xab (universe)
 Befehl \xbbtcal\xab aus dem Paket \xbbgcal\xab (universe)
 Befehl \xbbmcl\xab aus dem Paket \xbbmcl\xab (universe)
 Befehl \xbbccl\xab aus dem Paket \xbbcclive\xab (universe)
 Befehl \xbbtbl\xab aus dem Paket \xbbgroff-base\xab (main)
 Befehl \xbbncl\xab aus dem Paket \xbbncl-ncarg\xab (universe)
 Befehl \xbbgcl\xab aus dem Paket \xbbgcl\xab (universe)
 Befehl \xbbtdl\xab aus dem Paket \xbbtdl\xab (universe)
 Befehl \xbbtcc\xab aus dem Paket \xbbtcc\xab (universe)
 Befehl \xbbtcm\xab aus dem Paket \xbbtcm\xab (universe)
tcl: Befehl nicht gefunden.
bogdanbiv@bivub1404:~$ which tcl
bogdanbiv@bivub1404:~$ hgjkh
hgjkh: Befehl nicht gefunden.
```

Also what's wrong with the hex characters (\xbb and \xab).
My system is Kubuntu 14.04, trusty:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

My system language is English, however I have some regional settings set for my country:

```
$ locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_RO.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en:de:ro:en
LC_CTYPE="en_RO.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_RO.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_RO.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_RO.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_RO.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_RO.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_RO.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_RO.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_RO.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_RO.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_RO.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_RO.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Somehow I stumbled upon what may be some relevant information (see more at http://pastebin.com/4XGakzgL):

```
Command-not-found-Version: 0.3
Python-Version: 3.4.0 final 0
```

**UPDATE**: I tried various locale repair tools: a popup appeared saying I have incomplete language support and offered to help. That was nice, but it achieved nothing.
Well, at least now, the messages in German are displayed correctly in UTF and forcing English does work:

```
$ LANGUAGE=en tcl
No command 'tcl' found, did you mean:    # CORRECT, this should be normal behaviour 
$ LANGUAGE=en:de:ro tcl
Der Befehl »tcl« wurde nicht gefunden, meinten Sie vielleicht: # This is German
```

Here is the output of `locale` as of now:

```
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en:de:ro
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: What does `locale` say?

Comment: Added the output of `locale` to the question proper.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is the error line:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
```

When trying to print the messages, the C library will try the first locale in `LANGUAGE` which in your case is `en` but it has an error; so it switch to the second one which is `de` (german). And probably your `de` locale is not UFT-8 so you have the strange  hex data (probably `\xbb` and `\xab` are some kind of opening-closing quotation marks).

BTW, which locale is `en_RO`? In my system I have just the following:

```
en_AG,en_AG.utf8,en_AU.utf8,en_BW.utf8,en_CA.utf8,en_DK.utf8,en_GB.utf8,en_HK.utf8,en_IE.utf8,en_IN,en_IN.utf8,en_NG,en_NG.utf8,en_NZ.utf8,en_PH.utf8,en_SG.utf8,en_US.utf8,en_ZA.utf8,en_ZM,en_ZM.utf8,en_ZW.utf8
```

so you probably added it from some non-standard package? (I do not know, just asking).

Have you tried to check if the language support is completely loaded? (Settings -> Language Support in Gnome, it may vary with Ubuntu flavors). It sometime got quite scrambled up and selecting the option gives you this:

[image]

In my system it works ok and it switches language ok:

```
romano@pern:~$ tcl
No command 'tcl' found, did you mean:
 Command 'tcm' from package 'tcm' (universe)
 Command 'tcal' from package 'gcal' (universe)
 Command 'tcs' from package 'tcs' (universe)
 Command 'tdl' from package 'tdl' (universe)
 Command 'tcc' from package 'tcc' (universe)
 Command 'tel' from package 'orville-write' (universe)
 Command 'tjl' from package 'pvm-examples' (universe)
 Command 'gcl' from package 'gcl' (universe)
 Command 'mcl' from package 'mcl' (universe)
 Command 'ncl' from package 'ncl-ncarg' (universe)
 Command 'tbl' from package 'groff-base' (main)
 Command 'tc' from package 'iproute2' (main)
 Command 'cl' from package 'cl-launch' (universe)
 Command 'ccl' from package 'cclive' (universe)
 Command 'ecl' from package 'ecl' (universe)
tcl: command not found
```

and

```
romano@pern:~$ LANGUAGE=it:en tcl
Comando "tcl" non trovato. Forse si intendeva:
 Comando "ncl" dal pacchetto "ncl-ncarg" (universe)
 Comando "ecl" dal pacchetto "ecl" (universe)
 Comando "tel" dal pacchetto "orville-write" (universe)
 Comando "ccl" dal pacchetto "cclive" (universe)
 Comando "tdl" dal pacchetto "tdl" (universe)
 Comando "mcl" dal pacchetto "mcl" (universe)
 Comando "tcc" dal pacchetto "tcc" (universe)
 Comando "tc" dal pacchetto "iproute2" (main)
 Comando "tbl" dal pacchetto "groff-base" (main)
 Comando "cl" dal pacchetto "cl-launch" (universe)
 Comando "tcm" dal pacchetto "tcm" (universe)
 Comando "gcl" dal pacchetto "gcl" (universe)
 Comando "tcal" dal pacchetto "gcal" (universe)
 Comando "tjl" dal pacchetto "pvm-examples" (universe)
 Comando "tcs" dal pacchetto "tcs" (universe)
tcl: comando non trovato
```